# S Memo permissions

Tags: samsung, permissions, 8.0-oreo

So, I wanted to see install S Memo on an Android 8 device and, for some reason, S Memo asked for permission to read my contacts, messages, phone journal and location. Why does it need this stuff?

Comment: I accidentally spelled see

Comment: You can edit your question at any time to fix typos or add new information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`S Memo` can be used to share your notes with the contacts. You can text it to them, amongst other things.

On Android 8, if you deny these permissions, the app may not work properly, or may not work at all.  On apos written for the latest Android, you can deny selected permissions and the app is still supposed to work, albeit in a limited fashion.